# LinkedIn sdk for iOS

Tags: ios, sdk, linkedin-api

I am looking for the LinkedIn sdk that allows implementation with iOS devices, this is my first time when I am needed to work with the LinkedIn in an application, I am interested in retrieving the aptitudes(tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [IOSLinkedInAPI](https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI).

A small non intrusive library that makes it easy to authenticate and authorize against LinkedIn using OAuth2. The API uses a UIWebView to authenticate against LinkedIn.

**EDIT** : Yet another option [MALinkedIn](https://github.com/madapper/MALinkedIn)